# Which 'system' apps can be safely removed

Tags: macos, applications

I safely removed Front Row, Chess and Face Time which else system apps are safe to remove and which I should never touch?

I think it's a bad idea to remove "Dashboard.app" and "Launchpad.app".

Comment: Are you out of space? If so, I would buy an external hard-drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure why you would want to remove any of the apps that you mentioned — it’s not like they take up a lot of space or introduce security vulnerabilities or anything.

On the other hand, it would make sense to remove e.g. **Java**, for the reasons I mentioned before. If you don’t need Java, you can remove it by following these steps.

First of all you need to check which JVM (Java Virtual Machine) you have in your system. To do so, open Terminal.app, and enter:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/java_home –xml
```

If you you have JVM installed, you’ll get the `JVMHomePath` returned:

```
/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Then, remove JVM from your system:

```
# Wipe out the JVM installation location
sudo rm -rfv /System/Library/Java
```

After this, restart your Mac, and confirm JVM was successfully removed by running the first command again:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/java_home –xml
```

It should say something like:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try –request to install.
```

This means that it worked, and that your OS X Lion is Java-free again.

<sub>(This is an improved version of the instructions on http://stikine.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/howto-remove-java/.)</sub>

Comment: This is useful, but it answers a different question than the one being asked...

Comment: Java is shipped with OS X by default, and can safely be removed. It’s not an app in the strict sense of the word, but other than that I think it applies to OP’s situation. He seems to be trying to save space on his Mac.