# How to reinstall system apps

Tags: applications

How can I reinstall some system apps?

There could be different reasons for that:

- [I've removed some of my system apps](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47266/which-system-apps-can-be-safely-removed) and now I regret (actually not).
- Before I brought my computer to service center to replace corrupted memory it caused erratical disc writes which not only damaged some documents that I worked on but also corrupted some system apps (the part about documents is true).

Comment: There are also more interesting options on this thread. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how to reinstall some of them.

- Mount or your installation media.
- You may have hidden BaseSystem.dmg in your installation media (for me it's in root).
- Copy that BaseSystem.dmg somewhere and mount it to. It may contain Safari and Utilities:

[image: BaseSystem.dmg content]

- Now you can just drag them in /Applications if you need them

Comment: The volume can also be mounted from Lion's recovery partition with `diskutil mount "Recovery HD" && hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg`.